# svn:eol-style on repository level

Tags: svn, newline, line-endings

I'm trying to set up svn server (1.8.8) with enable-auto-props. I've read the 1.8 documentation but maybe I'm missing something. The server config file is like that:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes
[auto-props]
*.c     = svn:eol-style=native
*.h     = svn:eol-style=native
```

However when I check the repository 'auto props' (with client 1.8.11) I get nothing:
    svn pg svn:auto-prop --verbose -R svn://sources

Am I missing something?
According to : http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops#.VeL1MfmqpBc 
I should have got the auto-props , but I'm not ..

Answer (score 2):

1. Please, re-read referenced by you blog-post **carefully**: described by you current "old-style" way must be implemented **on client**: client will operate on properties of "just added" files
2. For new, RDC-style of properties you have to have `svn:auto-props` on the root of repository and after it you'll be able to ignore client's runtime settings

Comment: I've read it, but it's  still not clear (for me) how technically to set the svn:auto-props property on the root of repository ( in may case old existing repository)